# show/hide divs on hover

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I cannot get a div to show/hide upon hovering over another element.  I will eventually apply this to an image map, but i made a simple fiddle for the functionality.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
$('#a1').hover(function () {
$('#t1').toggleClass("hidden");
});
</script>

<style>
.hidden {display:none;}
</style>

<div id="a1">test a1</div>
<div id="t1" class="hidden">timeline 1</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4p7vLogd/

Comment: Well for one you aren't including the jquery library in your fiddle. It works fine when you do... http://jsfiddle.net/4p7vLogd/1/

Comment: Absolutely. Click on the drop down menu at the upper left corner and choose i.g. jQuery 2.0.2

Comment: and secondly, you need to wrap your jquery in a [document ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) block to ensure the elements exist before you try to access them

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="a1">test a1</div>
<div id="t1" class="hidden">timeline 1</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#a1').hover(function () {
        $('#t1').toggleClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

Make sure to include jQuery. Here's a forked fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/2eyzce7h/

If you're having issues with your functionality, consider using mouseenter() and mouseleave() instead of .hover().

Answer (score 0):

Mohammed's answer will work, but it's usually best practice to not hide something with CSS and depend on jQuery to show it in the off-chance that the user has Java disabled. This should also work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#a1').hide();

$('#a1').hover(
    function () {
        $('#t1').show();
    },
    function () {
        $('#t1').hide();
    });

});
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paulmz/fo5eo6f6/).